# The formula expression is invalid: Field Existing_Contact_Loop is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am updating an assignment node by adding a formula for the Premise County field but since the field is a Picklist, I am getting the below error:

IF( not(isblank({!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c})), {!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c}, {!$Record.Premise_County__c} )

Please assist with how to edit this formula. Thanks.

Comment: Hi  Makena , is  Premise County picklist field on Existing_Contact_Loop object?

Comment: Premise County is a Picklist field on the Contact object

Comment: Can you please send the error?

Comment: I am using a Formula in the Flow to check if the Premise County is already populated on the existing Contact and if so, leave it as is,  otherwise populate it.

Comment: Here is the error: "The formula expression is invalid: Field Existing_Contact_Loop is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions"

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

IF(
ISPICKVAL({!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c},''),
{!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c},
{!$Record.Premise_County__c}
)

if you want to check that picklist field is empty use ISPICKVAL({!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c},'')

Comment: I want to check that the picklist field is not blank that is populated with "{!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c}" or if blank (not populated then use "{!$Record.Premise_County__c} "

Answer (score 0):

You can try Text() to convert the picklist value and check Not(ISBLANK()) function to check it.

When you use the Picklist field to check or populate the values you have to use TEXT() or ISPICKVAL() functions .

```
IF(Not(ISBLANK(TEXT({!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c}))),{!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c},{!$Record.Premise_County__c})
```

Please find the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) module for the same.

Comment: I had tried this previously but got the same error

Comment: Is the flow record triggered on Contact object ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.
Adding "TEXT" converted the picklist values to text hence I was able to use this expression:

```
IF( NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT({!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c}))),
TEXT({!Existing_Contact_Loop.Premise_County__c}), 
TEXT({!$Record.Premise_County__c}) )
```